# Compare two files by hashCode

Tags: java, file, compare, arrays, hashcode

I need a class, that will find duplicates in the array. I have a sorted list, in which files will compared on size, and then I want to compare them on (hashCode?) some criterions.

```
public class FileComparison {

public void compare(ArrayList<File> arrayOfFiles) throws Exception {


    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int y = i + 1; y < arrayOfFiles.size() - 1; y++) {
            if(arrayOfFiles.get(i).length() == arrayOfFiles.get(y).length()) {
                //byte[] b1; 
                //byte[] b2;
                //don't know what to do     
            }
            if(arrayOfFiles.get(i).length() != arrayOfFiles.get(y).length()) {
                break;
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

If the size of both files is same - it needs to compare them by another way. If they are same also on this way - files are duplicates.
If size is different - they are not a duplicates.

Comment: It is fairly easy to find some hash functions implemented in a few lines of code in Java on the internet. What stops you to do so ?

Comment: All that i have already find and try to use - doesn't work

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. If two files are different, then what? If two files are the same, then what? If two files are the same size but different hashCodes? If the files are not the same size but have the same hashCode?

Comment: @Dici you don't need to look on the Internet. The built-in `java.security.MessageDigest` will do this for you.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt What I meant is that the internet is full of samples of code using the `java.security` package to do such things

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to calculate the MD5 checksum and compare them by it:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.DigestInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class MD5 {

    public static String getMD5Sum(String filePath) throws Exception{

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath))) {
          DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
          int read = 0;
          do{
              read = dis.read();
          }while(read > -1);
        }
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        digest.toString();
         String result = "";

           for (int i=0; i < digest.length; i++) {
               result += Integer.toString( ( digest[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1     );
           }
           return result;
    }
}
```

The method getMD5Sum will return the MD5 cehchsum of the file.